# grunt-contrib-concat not including certain file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

When using the command `NODE_ENV=development grunt`, `grunt-contrib-concat` isn't concatenating `public/javascripts/environments/app.development.js`.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    src: {
      config: ['public/javascripts/environments/app.<%= env %>.js'],
      javascripts: ['public/javascripts/**/*.js', '!public/javascripts/environments/**/*.js']
    },
    concat: {
      javascript: {
        src: ['<%= src.config %>', '<%= src.javascripts %>'],
        dest: 'app.full.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:javascript']);
};
```

If I remove `!public/javascripts/environments/**/*.js` from line 6, both of my environment-specific files (`app.development.js` and `app.production.js`) get concatenated, like so:

```
angular.module('realscout').constant('API_BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:3000'); // <-- `app.development.js`

angular.module('realscout', [
  'realscout.services'
]);


angular.module('realscout').constant('API_BASE_URL', 'http://api.realscout.com/v3'); // <-- `app.production.js`
angular.module('realscout.services', [
  'realscout.services.property'
]);

angular.module('realscout.services.property', []);
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this,

> '!public/javascripts/environments/**/*.js'

Try:

> 'public/javascripts/environments/!(**/*).js'